# Should processing logic of STRIPE be in the Laravel controller or in the validator?

Tags: laravel, validation, request, rules

I am a newcomer to laravel. I have a controller ProductController like this

```
    public function buy(Request $request, User $user) {

    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
        'amount' => 100,
        'currency' => 'aud',
        'description' => 'Example charge',
        'source' => $token,
    ]);

    if ($charge->status === "succeeded") {
        //-- Processing... --//
    }
```

I would like to ask the more appropriate design style, should I put the part of STTRIE in other places, such as the validator.
If yes, it is to make a rule and a request than verify it in the validator ?

Can someone tell me how to use the rule in the request?

Comment: Neither place is likely the best place for it.  Business logic should live in models or service classes.

Comment: are you validating the stripe `$charge` or your `$request`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a Stripe charge is not request validation. It's an API call to Stripe. So, it should definitely not stay in the validator.

You can have this logic in a controller for small apps, but for medium/large scale apps with abstraction (e.g. if you want to have the option later to change the payment provider from Stripe to say Braintree), it should be in a service class.

Also, never use `$_POST` directly. Use `$request->input` instead. As a thumb rule, if you have 2 ways to do something in code, always use the way that implements higher level libraries (libraries > then framework > then core PHP).

Answer (score 0):

To write the validation using Laravel 5.5+

```
public function buy(Request $request, User $user)
{
    // first define your rules
    $rules = [
        'amount' => 'required|numeric'
    ];

    $validatedData = $request->validate($rules);

    // The purchase is valid...
}
```

For Laravel 5.0 - 5.4:

```
public function buy(Request $request, User $user)
{
    // first define your rules
    $rules = [
        'amount' => 'required|numeric'
    ];

    $validatedData = $this->validate($rules);

    // The purchase is valid...
}
```

The typical responsibilities of a controller in my opinion:

1. Take in a request
2. Return a response

I think it is probably fine to have one conditional or validation check.

Comment: Thank you @adam. I prefer to separate the logic into different places so that the controller doesn't look too messy. I originally thought that I would customize a STRIPE rule and then use it in laravel's request.